# Best way to keep globla data AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing an app that the goal is to manage some clients connected through socket.io. I have to manage they state (connected/disconnected) and also real time details of the clients like errors emitted. I have tried 2 different approaches, setting listeners on controllers and creating services. The problem with the controller approach is that I have to repeat emits to get the most current data every time a controller is loaded. With the services I have the problem that there is a global listener (receives general notifications from all clients) and I cant figure how to manipulate a service from another service (I dont think you can). I've been thinking on implementing a global controller that all controllers can inherit from or appending my data to $rootScope. Before I go either way. I was wondering to hear from more experienced angular devs as to what would be better approach from such app and manage global data?

Thanks

Comment: That's the purpose of $rootScope, but be smart and don't abuse it.

Comment: I think a service is a better way to go. A service can depend on another service through dependency injection: app.factory('myService', function(myDependentService) {...});

Comment: @pixelbits I had an issue with that. Kept saying that the injected service was undefined. But I do agree, IMO I think services is the more elegant way.

Comment: Its likely you're doing something wrong - the approach is sound.

Comment: @pixelbits I tried combining providers but still have the same issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/CHvjr4Z0UwRCxJAvXWHB?p=preview that is a plunker that if look at the console you will see the problem. The problem is in the notifications provider there are some comments that explain what Ive tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.provider('notifications',['socket', 'redisMsg', function(socket, redis) {
```

You are defining a provider, and injecting instances of the service (socket, redisMsg) at the same time. This is not allowed.  In a provider, you can only inject other providers.  If you need instances, then $get should be injected with those instances rather than in the provider function:

```
  .provider('notifications',[function() {
    var notifications = [];
    return {
        $get: ['socket', 'redisMsg', function(socket, redis) {
            return {
                listen: function() {
                    // complains in the line below
                    // unknown provider socket
                    // if I change to socketProvider
                    // still fails with
                    // undefined is not a function
                    socket.on('redis', function(msg) {
                        redis.processRedis(msg);
                        var message = redis.getMessage();
                        if (message.action !== 'jobRunning') {
                            notifications.push(message);
                        }
                        if (message.action === 'PeberryChange') {
                            socket.emit('get-peberries');
                        }
                        console.log(message);
                    });
                },
                getNotifications: function(action) {
                    if (typeof action !== 'undefined') {
                        return alert("NOT DONE YET BRUH!!!");
                    }
                    return notifications;
                }
            };
        }]
    };
}])
```

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/S2YbHRtji3T6JG11vqHL?p=preview)